# Laravel Passport & MFA Integration

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, one-time-password, multi-factor-authentication

in a project i'm working on, i use laravel passport. i'm trying to integrate MFA (multi factor authentication) into the laravel passport, but i failed. my research on the internet did not yield a result. do we have friends working on such a system? if so, what are the ways they follow?